# Testing using Mocha js for a function with multiple "map"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

Below code is only for rough explanation; As you can see we need multiple returns for each "map" function to get a return from js;

How does one test this function using mocha?
i.e we cant place multiple returns just to get the value for our testing purposes because such returns will disturb the actual implementation of said function.

So I need to avoid unnecessary returns for implementation sake but need the same multiple returns for testing..

Suggestions please?

```js
var array = ["a","b","c"], 
    array1 = ["1","2","3"],
    array2 = [],
    returnVar;
function test() {
  return ("done")
   array.map(function(data) {
     return ("done")
     array1.map(function(datum){
        array2.push(datum)
        return("done")
     });     
   });   
}
returnVar = test();
alert(returnVar)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not testable code, therefore it is hard for it to create test in current shape.

`map` is used for data transformations, therefore you would isolate your data transformation into function with input and output value. Testing that function would be matter of providing input, calling function and verification of output.

Answer (score 0):

You can stub `Array.prototype.map` method, but better way would be to test functions being passed to `map` in isolation as @luboskrnac proposed.